# Valgrind memory leak with dynamic arrays and structs C

Tags: c, arrays, memory, memory-leaks

I have problem with my code. Code compiles and runs without warnings or errors and does that I wanted, but Valgrind finds memory leaks that I couldn't repair. I was unable to correct code myself for several days. Can you please point out that I am doing wrong?

This is exercise, and source.c is the code that I have made myself, everything else was already given. Idea was that I need to create dynamic array that contains Student structs in consecutive slots.

As I understand, Valgrind thinks that in create_student malloc allocated too little memory for array entry and then test function (server side thing in our university) while compering my name string with its somehow points at NULL pointer and goes out memory bounds.

I tried several approaches and this gives no errors or warnings by compiler (Code::Blocks) and works as intended but Valgrind still doesn't like it..

Thank you in the advance!

Valgrind output:

```
==358== Invalid read of size 8
==358==    at 0x4016CB: test_create_student (test_source.c:38)
==358==    by 0x406340: srunner_run_all (in /tmc/test/test)
==358==    by 0x40288A: tmc_run_tests (tmc-check.c:121)
==358==    by 0x402544: main (test_source.c:310)
==358==  Address 0x518d768 is 0 bytes after a block of size 56 alloc'd
==358==    at 0x4C244E8: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:236)
==358==    by 0x402C5D: create_student (source.c:18)
==358==    by 0x401690: test_create_student (test_source.c:35)
==358==    by 0x406340: srunner_run_all (in /tmc/test/test)
==358==    by 0x40288A: tmc_run_tests (tmc-check.c:121)
==358==    by 0x402544: main (test_source.c:310)
==358== 
==358== Invalid read of size 1
==358==    at 0x4C25D94: strcmp (mc_replace_strmem.c:426)
==358==    by 0x4016DC: test_create_student (test_source.c:38)
==358==    by 0x406340: srunner_run_all (in /tmc/test/test)
==358==    by 0x40288A: tmc_run_tests (tmc-check.c:121)
==358==    by 0x402544: main (test_source.c:310)
==358==  Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==358== 
==358== 
==358== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==358==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x0
==358==    at 0x4C25D94: strcmp (mc_replace_strmem.c:426)
==358==    by 0x4016DC: test_create_student (test_source.c:38)
==358==    by 0x406340: srunner_run_all (in /tmc/test/test)
==358==    by 0x40288A: tmc_run_tests (tmc-check.c:121)
==358==    by 0x402544: main (test_source.c:310)
==358==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
==358==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
==358==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
==358==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
==358==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 8388608.
```

This is source file:

```
#include "source.h"
#include "string.h"
#include "stdlib.h"

 /* Parameters:
 * s: pointer to the Students main structure (allocated by caller)
 * name: name of student
 * id: Student ID
 * age: age
 * course: course code
 * Returns: pointer to the student element in the array
 */
Student *create_student(Students *s, const char *name, const char *id,
        unsigned char age, const char *course)
{
    if(s->count == 0){
        s->array = malloc(sizeof(Student));
        if(s->array == NULL)
            return NULL;
    }
    if(s->count > 0){
        Student *nptr = realloc(s->array, (s->count+1)*sizeof(Student));
        if(nptr == NULL)
            return NULL;
        else
            s->array = nptr;
    }

    s->array[s->count].name = malloc((strlen(name)+1));                 /*Allocating memory for name pointer*/
    if(s->array[s->count].name == NULL)
        return NULL;
    memcpy(s->array[s->count].name, name, strlen(name));               /*Copying name string to the *name array*/
    s->array[s->count].name[strlen(name)] = '\0';

    if(strlen(id) > 8|| strlen(course) > 16)                            /*Checks if the strings are correct length*/
        return NULL;
    memcpy(s->array[s->count].id, id, strlen(id));                   /*Copying rest of the files*/
    s->array[s->count].id[strlen(id)] = '\0';
    memcpy(s->array[s->count].course, course, strlen(course));
    s->array[s->count].course[strlen(course)] = '\0';
    s->array[s->count].age = age;
    s->array[s->count].points = NULL;
    s->array[s->count].numPoints = 0;

    s->count++;                                                         /*Count is incremented by one as the first student is created*/
    s->array = &s->array[0];                                            /*Now *array points at the first entry in the array*/

    return &s->array[s->count];                                         /*Returns newly created pointer to the student*/
}


/* Parameters:
 * s: pointer to the Students main structure
 * id: Student ID to be looked for
 * course: Course code to be looked for
 * Returns: pointer to the student element in array, if found. NULL if not found
 */
Student *find_student(Students *s, const char *id, const char *course)
{
    Student *ptr = s->array;                                /*Creating pointer that points at the current student structure (starts from the beginning)*/
    int r1, r2;
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < s->count; i++){
        r1 = strcmp(ptr->course, course);                   /*Checks for ID and course number*/
        r2 = strcmp(ptr->id, id);
        if(r1 == 0 && r2 == 0){
            return ptr;                                     /*Returns pointer to the student structure if matches*/
        }
        ptr++;
    }
    return NULL;                                            /*Returns NULL if no such student found*/
}

/* Parameters:
 * s: pointer to the Students main structure
 * id: Student ID to be deleted
 * course: Course from which student is deleted
 * Returns: 1 if deletion was successful, 0 if not (e.g. student not found)
 */
int delete_student(Students *s, const char *id, const char *course)
{
    Student *st0 = s->array;                                        /*Pointer at the first element in the array*/
    Student *stl = st0;                                             /*Pointer at the last element in the array*/
    for(int i = 0; i < (s->count-1); i++)
        stl++;
    if(find_student(s, id, course) == st0){                         /*1. Deleting the first element in the array*/
        s->count--;
        free(st0->name);
        for(int i = 0; i < s->count; i++)
            memcpy(st0+i, st0+(i+1), sizeof(Student));
        s->array = realloc(s->array, (s->count)*sizeof(Student));
        return 1;
    }
    else if(find_student(s, id, course) == stl){                    /*2. Deleting the last element in the array*/
        s->count--;
        free(stl->name);
        s->array = realloc(s->array, (s->count)*sizeof(Student));
        return 1;
    }
    else if(find_student(s, id, course) != NULL){                   /*3. Deleting the element in the middle of array*/
        int a = 0;
        while(st0 != find_student(s, id, course)){
            a++;
            st0++;
        }
        free(st0->name);
        s->count--;
        for(int i = 0; i < s->count-a; i++){
            memcpy(st0+i, st0+(i+1), sizeof(Student));
        }
        s->array = realloc(s->array, (s->count)*sizeof(Student));
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}


/* Parameters:
 * s: pointer to the Students main structure
 * id: student ID to set the points
 * course: course ID to set the points
 * points: array of points to be set to the student (will replace previous entry)
 * len: length of the points array
 * Returns: 1 if setting points was successful, 0 if not (e.g. student not found)
 */
int set_points(Students *s, const char *id, const char *course, const float *points, int len)
{
    Student *st = find_student(s, id, course);
    if(st != NULL){
        if(st->points == NULL){
            st->points = malloc(len * sizeof(int));
            for(int i = 0; i < len; i++)
                st->points[i] = points[i];
            st->numPoints = len;
            return 1;
        }
        else{
            st->points = realloc(st->points, len * sizeof(int));
            for(int i = 0; i < len; i++)
                st->points[i] = points[i];
            st->numPoints = len;
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And this is source.h:

```
typedef struct student Student;

struct student {
    char *name; // name of the student
    char id[8]; // null-terminated student ID
    unsigned char age;
    char course[16]; // null-terminated course code;
    float *points; // pointer to dynamic array of exercise points
    unsigned int numPoints; // length of the above array
};

typedef struct {
    unsigned int count; // size of the students array
    Student *array; // pointer to the first element in the array
} Students;

Student *create_student(Students *s, const char *name, const char *id,
        unsigned char age, const char *course);
Student *find_student(Students *s, const char *id, const char *course);
int delete_student(Students *s, const char *id, const char *course);
int set_points(Students *s, const char *id, const char *course, const float *points, int len);
```

And this is main:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "source.h"

void print_students(Students *s)
{
    Student *st = s->array;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < s->count; i++) {
        printf("%s (%s), Course: %s, Age: %d\n", st->name, st->id, st->course, st->age);
        if (st->numPoints) {
            printf(" -- Points: ");
            for (unsigned int j = 0; j < st->numPoints; j++)
                printf("%f  ", st->points[j]);
            printf("\n");
        }
        st++;
    }
}

void initialize_reg(Students *reg) {
    assert(reg != NULL);
    reg->count = 0;
    reg->array = NULL;
    create_student(reg, "Teemu Teekkari", "00000A", 20, "ELEC-A1100");
    create_student(reg, "Matti Meikäläinen", "12345B", 28, "ELEC-A1100");
    create_student(reg, "Wow", "33333C", 28, "ELEC-A1100");
    create_student(reg, "Much Student", "98765H", 28, "ELEC-A1100");
    create_student(reg, "Such course", "12121R", 28, "ELEC-A1111");
    create_student(reg, "Amaze", "11111T", 28, "ELEC-A1111");
}

int main()
{
    Students s;
    s.count = 0;
    s.array = NULL;

    // create a group of students using create_student
    initialize_reg(&s);
    print_students(&s);

    // Try find_student 
    Student *sf3 = find_student(&s, "33333C", "ELEC-A1100");
    Student *sf6 = find_student(&s, "11111T", "ELEC-A1111");
    if (!sf3) {
        printf("Did not find existing student 33333C\n");
    } else if (strcmp(sf3->id, "33333C")) {
        printf("Incorrect student ID %s when should have been 33333C\n", sf3->id);
    }
    if (!sf6) {
        printf("Did not find existing student 11111T\n");
    } else if (strcmp(sf6->id, "11111T")) {
        printf("Incorrect student ID %s when should have been 11111T\n", sf6->id);
    }

    // Try delete_student with existing student
    if (!delete_student(&s, "12121R", "ELEC-A1111")) {
        printf("Delete student failed for existing student\n");
    }

    printf("-----\n");
    float p[] = {3.0, 1.0, 4.0, 4.5};
    set_points(&s, "00000A", "ELEC-A1100", p, 4);
    print_students(&s);
    printf("-----\n");

    // Try delete_student with non_existing student
    delete_student(&s, "33333C", "ELEC-A1100");
    print_students(&s);
}
```

This is test_source to which Valgrind refers to:

```
#include <check.h>
#include "tmc-check.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <time.h>
#include "../src/source.h"

void release_memory(Students *s) {
    unsigned int i;
    if (s->array) {
        for (i = 0; i < s->count; i++) {
            Student *st = &(s->array[i]);
            if (st->name)
                free(st->name);
            if (st->points)
                free(st->points);
        }
        free(s->array);
    }
}

START_TEST(test_create_student) {
    Students reg;
    //assert(reg != NULL);
    reg.count = 0;
    reg.array = NULL;
    char buf[160];

    //char *name = malloc(strlen("Teemu Teekkari") + 1);
    //strcpy(name, "Teemu Teekkari");
    char *name = "Teemu Teekkari";

    Student *s1 = create_student(&reg, name, "00000A", 20, "ELEC-A1100");
    fail_unless(s1 != NULL, "[Task 3.4.a] create_student returned NULL.\n");

    if (strcmp(name, s1->name)) {
        sprintf(buf, "[Task 3.4.a] Student name should be %s, was %s.\n", name, s1->name);
        release_memory(&reg);
        fail(buf);
    }

    if (strcmp("00000A", s1->id)) {
        sprintf(buf, "[Task 3.4.a] Student ID should be %s, was %s.\n", "00000A", s1->id);
        release_memory(&reg);
        fail(buf);
    }

    if (s1->age != 20) {
        sprintf(buf, "[Task 3.4.a] Student age should be 20, was %d\n.", s1->age);
        release_memory(&reg);
        fail(buf);
    }

    if (strcmp("ELEC-A1100", s1->course)) {
        sprintf(buf, "[Task 3.4.a] Course code not should be %s, was %s.\n", "ELEC-A1100", s1->course);
        release_memory(&reg);
        fail(buf);
    }

    if (s1->points != NULL) {
        sprintf(buf, "[Task 3.4.a] Points array should be NULL, was %p.\n", s1->points);
        release_memory(&reg);
        fail(buf);
    }

    if (s1->numPoints != 0) {
        sprintf(buf, "[Task 3.4.a] numPoints should be 0, was %d.\n", s1->numPoints);
        release_memory(&reg);
        fail(buf);
    }

    //free(name);
    //fail_unless(!strcmp("Teemu Teekkari", s1->name), "[Task 17.1] Student name was not allocated from heap.");

    if (reg.count != 1) {
        sprintf(buf, "[Task 3.4.a] After adding a student, student count should be 1, was %d.\n",
                reg.count);
        release_memory(&reg);
        fail(buf);
    }

    if (reg.array != s1) {
        release_memory(&reg);
        fail("[Task 3.4.a] After adding one student, the returned value does not point to the beginning of array.\n");
    }

    Student *s2 = create_student(&reg, "Peppilotta Sikuriina Rullakartiina Kissanminttu Efraimintytar Pitkatossu", "12345B", 10, "ELEC-A1100");
    if ((reg.array) + 1 != s2) {
        release_memory(&reg);
        fail("[Task 3.4.a] After adding second student, the returned value does not point to the second array member.\n");
    }

    if (reg.count != 2) {
        sprintf(buf, "[Task 3.4.a] After adding second student, the student count should be 2, was %d.\n",
                reg.count);
        release_memory(&reg);
        fail(buf);
    }

#if 0
    Student *s3 = create_student(&reg, "Ylimaaraisia Merkkeja", "99999Ffoofoofoofoo", 60, "ELEC-A1111-even-16-characters-is-too-much-for-a-course-code");
    assert(s3 != NULL);

    if (strcmp("99999Ff", s3->id)) {
        sprintf("[Task 3.4.a] Too long student id truncated incorrectly: %s, should be %s\n",
                s3->id, "99999Ff");
        release_memory(&reg);
        fail(buf);
    }
    if (strcmp("ELEC-A1111-even", s3->course)) {
        sprintf(buf, "[Task 3.4.a] Too long course code truncated incorrectly: %s, should be %s\n",
                s3->course, "ELEC-A1111-even");
        release_memory(&reg);
        fail(buf);
    }
#endif
    release_memory(&reg);
}

END_TEST

Students *initialize_reg(Students *reg) {
    //Students *reg = malloc(sizeof(Students));
    assert(reg != NULL);
    reg->count = 0;
    reg->array = NULL;
    create_student(reg, "Teemu Teekkari", "00000A", 20, "ELEC-A1100");
    create_student(reg, "Matti Meikäläinen", "12345B", 28, "ELEC-A1100");
    create_student(reg, "Wow", "33333C", 28, "ELEC-A1100");
    create_student(reg, "Much Student", "98765H", 28, "ELEC-A1100");
    create_student(reg, "Such course", "12121R", 28, "ELEC-A1111");
    create_student(reg, "Amaze", "11111T", 28, "ELEC-A1111");
    return reg;
}

START_TEST(test_find_student) {
    Students regb;
    char buf[160];
    Students *reg = initialize_reg(&regb);
    Student *sf3 = find_student(reg, "33333C", "ELEC-A1100");
    Student *sf6 = find_student(reg, "11111T", "ELEC-A1111");

    if (sf3 == NULL) {
        release_memory(reg);
        fail("[Task 3.4.b] find_student returned NULL for existing student ID %s.\n", "33333C");
    }

    if (strcmp(sf3->id, "33333C")) {
        sprintf(buf, "[Task 3.4.b] find_student returned student with wrong id. Searched for: %s, returned: %s", "33333C", sf3->id);
        release_memory(reg);
        fail(buf);
    }

    if (sf6 == NULL) {
        release_memory(reg);
        fail("[Task 3.4.b] find_student returned NULL for existing student %s.\n", "11111T");
    }

    if (strcmp(sf6->id, "11111T")) {
        sprintf(buf, "[Task 3.4.b] find_student returned student with wrong id. Searched for: %s, returned: %s", "11111T", sf6->id);
        release_memory(reg);
        fail(buf);
    }

    if (NULL != find_student(reg, "98989D", "ELEC-A1112")) {
        release_memory(reg);
        fail("[Task 3.4.b] find_student should return NULL for nonexistent students.\n");
    }

    /*    fail_unless(NULL == find_student(reg, "98989D", "ELEC-A1100"), "[Task 17.2] find_student should return NULL for nonexistent students.");
        fail_unless(NULL == find_student(reg, "33333C", "ELEC-A1112"), "[Task 17.2] find_student should return NULL for nonexistent students.");
        fail_unless(NULL == find_student(reg, "33333C", "ELEC-A1111"), "[Task 17.2] find_student should return NULL for nonexistent students.");*/
    release_memory(reg);
}

END_TEST


START_TEST(test_delete_student) {
    char buf[160];
    Students regb;
    Students *reg = initialize_reg(&regb);
    if (reg->count != 6) {
        sprintf(buf, "[Task 3.4.c] Wrong student count after adding 6 students, you have %d\n.",
                reg->count);
        release_memory(reg);
        fail(buf);
    }

    if (!delete_student(reg, "11111T", "ELEC-A1111")) {
        sprintf(buf, "[Task 3.4.c] delete_student() failed for existing student 11111T.\n");
        release_memory(reg);
        fail(buf);
    }

    if (reg->count != 5) {
        sprintf(buf, "[Task 3.4.c] After deleting one student, student count should be 5, you had %d.\n",
                reg->count);
        release_memory(reg);
        fail(buf);
    }

    if (!delete_student(reg, "33333C", "ELEC-A1100")) {
        sprintf(buf, "[Task 3.4.c] delete_student() failed for existing student 33333C.\n");
        release_memory(reg);
        fail(buf);
    }
    //fail_unless(reg->count == 4, "[Task 17.3] Wrong student count after deletion.");

    assert((reg->array + 2) != NULL);

    if (strcmp((reg->array + 2)->id, "98765H")) {
        sprintf(buf, "[Task 3.4.c] After deleting student 33333C, student %s should be in 3rd array position. You have %s.\n", "98765H", (reg->array + 2)->id);
        release_memory(reg);
        fail(buf);
    }

    if (delete_student(reg, "33330C", "ELEC-A1101")) {
        release_memory(reg);
        fail("[Task 3.4.c] delete_student() should have failed for nonexisting student 33330C.\n");
    }
    /*fail_unless(delete_student(reg, "00000A", "ELEC-A1111") == 0, "[Task 17.3] delete_student() should have failed for nonexisting student.");
    fail_unless(delete_student(reg, "12121R", "ELEC-A1100") == 0, "[Task 17.3] delete_student() should have failed for nonexisting student.");
    fail_unless(delete_student(reg, "00000A", "ELEC-A1100"), "[Task 17.3] delete_student() failed for existing student 00000A.");
    fail_unless(delete_student(reg, "12345B", "ELEC-A1100"), "[Task 17.3] delete_student() failed for existing student 12345B.");
    fail_unless(delete_student(reg, "98765H", "ELEC-A1100"), "[Task 17.3] delete_student() failed for existing student 98765H.");
    fail_unless(delete_student(reg, "12121R", "ELEC-A1111"), "[Task 17.3] delete_student() failed for existing student 12121R.");

    fail_unless(reg->count == 0, "[Task 17.3] Course register should be empty after deleting all students.");*/

    release_memory(reg);
}

END_TEST


void pr_array(char *buf, float *arr, int n) {
    char b[40];
    sprintf(buf, "{");
    while (n--) {
        sprintf(b, "%.1f", *arr++);
        if (n)
            strcat(b, ", ");
        strcat(buf, b);
    }
    strcat(buf, "}");
}

START_TEST(test_set_points) {
    Students regb;
    Students *reg = initialize_reg(&regb);
    char arrbuf[80];
    char buf[160];
    float p[4];
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        p[i] = (float)(rand() % 10) / 2;
    }
    pr_array(arrbuf, p, 4);

    if (!set_points(reg, "00000A", "ELEC-A1100", p, 4)) {
        sprintf(buf, "[Task 3.4.d] set_points() returned 0 for student 00000A with array %s, but it should have succeeded.\n",
                arrbuf);
        release_memory(reg);
        fail(buf);
    }
    Student *st = &(reg->array[0]);

    if (st->points == NULL) {
        sprintf(buf, "[Task 3.4.d] Points array not created for array %s (is still NULL).\n",
                arrbuf);
        release_memory(reg);
        fail(buf);
    }

    char arr2[80];
    pr_array(arr2, st->points, 4);
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        if (st->points[i] != p[i]) {
            sprintf(buf, "[Task 3.4.d] Point array differs. Should be %s. You have %s\n",
                    arrbuf, arr2);
            release_memory(reg);
            fail(buf);
        }
    }
    /*float q[] = {2, 5, 1, 6, 12, 1};
    fail_unless(set_points(reg, "00000A", "ELEC-A1100", q, 6) == 1, "[Task 17.4] set_points() did not return 1 on success or failed when it was not supposed to");
    fail_unless(st->points != NULL, "[Task 17.4] Points array for student not created");
    fail_unless(st->points[4] == 12, "[Task 17.4] Setting points failed on student");
    fail_unless(set_points(reg, "00000A", "ELEC-A1111", p, 3) == 0, "[Task 17.4] set_points() did not return 0 on failure");*/

    release_memory(reg);
}

END_TEST


int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    srand((unsigned) time(NULL));
    Suite *s = suite_create("Test-3.4");

    /* TODO: define tests */
    tmc_register_test(s, test_create_student, "3.4.a");
    tmc_register_test(s, test_find_student, "3.4.b");
    tmc_register_test(s, test_delete_student, "3.4.c");
    tmc_register_test(s, test_set_points, "3.4.d");

    return tmc_run_tests(argc, argv, s);
}
```

Comment: When you copy strings, why not use `strcpy` instead of `memcpy` plus adding termination character? Or even use `strdup` to make it even simpler? Like in `s->array[s->count].name = strdup(name);`

Comment: Also, you checks for e.g. the `id` and `course` fields are wrong. They allow for string of length `8` and `16` (respectively) which leaves no space for the string terminator. Oh, and here to a plain [`strcpy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy) would have been better.

Comment: I have tried using strcpy and it still gives same Valgrind error. And all ID are length of 6 + \0 and course length of 10 +\0, so terminating NULL should be in id and course arrays..

Comment: While it's no problem *now*, they are still *potential* problems. And everything that makes the source simpler are, IMO, good.

Comment: As for your problem, you did notice that the errors all happen in a function called `test_create_student`, which you don't show? Also, to catch the segmentation fault, run the program in a debugger, it will stop at the location of the crash, allowing you to examine and walk the function call stack, as well as examine values of variables.

Comment: test_create_student is function in test source file which is run on university server and basically comperes output of my code with theirs. I have tried to run debugger but it tells that there is no errors and everything is fine.

Comment: Maybe there is better way to do create_student function, but then I do it differently I get errors then I try to put Student structs in array. It just seems to me that s->array[s->count].something is the only viable option here, but I am surely mistaken.

Comment: Well that's where a couple of the errors seems to be, for example the segmentation fault seems to be a `strcmp` call with a `NULL` pointer ("Access not within mapped region at address 0x0").

Comment: The assignment `s->array = &s->array[0]` in `create_student` is not needed, `s->array` *already* points to the first `Student` structure in the "array". Also, you return a pointer to *beyond* the allocated memory, you need to return `&s->array[s->count - 1]` to return the last `Student`.

Comment: I added text_source code. I even downloaded it again from university page and tried to check my code with new version of it, but it still shows same Valgrind error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And with the test source code, combined with my last comment, it's now easy to see the problem:

You return a `Student` pointer that points *beyond* the allocated memory.

By the point the `create_student` function returns, you have increased `s->count` so it's the number of entries in the "array" `s->array`. But size array-indices are zero-base, the max index is `s->count - 1` at that point.

Comment: Oh my god, it finally works! Thank you very very much! I feel so stupid, wasted 3 days staring at code and trying to find problem and then it was just this little thing that caused this.. C is unforgiving. Thank you once more!

Answer (score 1):

The `create_student()` function ends with:

```
s->count++;   /*Count is incremented by one as the first student is created*/
s->array = &s->array[0];   /*Now *array points at the first entry in the array*/
return &s->array[s->count];   /*Returns newly created pointer to the student*/
```

I'm epically sceptic towards this code.

The first line is fine; there's one more student stored now than there was before the function ran. The comment is broken though.

The second line is broken, it re-assigns `array`, a newly allocated dynamic pointer. You should never do that. Fortunately it's a no-op, setting it to itself. The comment implies that you think it does something though, which makes it scary.

The third line is super-scary; it returns a pointer to *once past the array*, remember that `count` has been incremented.

If called with `count == 0`, the function `malloc()`s space for a single `Student`, then returns a pointer to the second element in an array of one. Bad!